# The law of syllogism example

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Could anyone give me an example that applies to the law of syllogism?

My law looks like this:

$$(P \to Q)\wedge(Q\to R)\to(P\to R)$$

Comment: See [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  you are smart you like Math. $$(P\to Q)$$
If you like Math you get a good job.$$(Q\to R)$$
Thus

If you are smart you get a good job.$$(P\to R)$$